# Casting perform selector to SEL under objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector

I created a `UIButton` with the following code:

```
UIButton* queenButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
queenButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,30,30);
[queenButton setTitle:@"Q" forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
[queenButton addTarget:self action:(SEL)[self performSelector:@selector(promotePawnAt:to:) withObject:end withObject:@"Q"] forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

When I do this the compiler gives an error that says, `Cast of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL' is disallowed with ARC`. When I remove the `(SEL)` cast, I get `Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'SEL' is disallowed with ARC`.

What I want to do is get the program to call `promotePawnAt:to:` when the button is pushed, but that function takes arguments, so `@selector(promotePawnAt:to:)` wouldn't work.

Comment: So then you make assumptions instead of thinking logically... Wonderful...

Comment: (Hint: you can't do directly what you want. Either re-design your code, or use a custom button subclass with a property holding whatever information you want to associate with it, or use the Obejctive-C associated object APIs, etc...)

Comment: Why don't you just call that method from within the Button's action method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it this way. You must create a method with one argument and add it as button's action.

```
[queenButton addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and inside call yout method:

```
-(void)action:(id)button {
[self promotePawnAt:end to:@"Q"];
}
```

Comment: That's disappointing that I can't do it that way. However, there are only four possible arguments (Q, R, B, and N) so I suppose I can create a method for each of those four arguments. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can also create a dictionary to map buttons to their arguments